# How can I include Flash in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, controls, flash

I would like to create a .exe wrapper for a Flash Player using VB.NET. I am having a few problems.

1.I seem to remember being able to import Flash Player as a control into Visual Studio (2008 Pro). For some reason, I can't seem to VS to import it anymore. (I tried using the OCX from Visual Studio) Perhaps I'm looking for the wrong file. *What file am I looking for?*

2.Is including Flash inside of a VB program legal?

3.When a control is included in a VB.NET program (such as Flash) does the control need to be distributed in a separate file, or will the compiled application contain it in the ".exe"?

Thanks.

**edit:**

I was able to import the control as the Flash10b.ocx from c:\Windows\System32\Macromed directory as a COM component. Question 2 and 3 still remain.

**Edit 2:**

Is there documentation on the ActiveX control? I am trying top figure out the API for ExternalInterface. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. Using flash inside a VB program is perfectly legal, it is just an activeX control.
3. You will need to distribute the interop library with your application (it will be in your output directory) and the ActiveX object (flash10b.ocx) will need to be installed on the system, it wont package it all up for you.